# why the highlighted series is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

In course of reading Kesavan’s Functional Analysis text I got stuck in the following example. I cannot understand why the highlighted series under the given conditions is convergent.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the condition

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_{ij}p_i \leqslant \beta p_j$$

for all $j\in \mathbb{N}$, by nonnegativity we obtain

$$a_{kj}p_k \leqslant \beta p_j$$

for all $k,j\in \mathbb{N}$, and from that

$$\frac{a_{kj}}{p_j} \leqslant \frac{\beta}{p_k}.$$

So $0 \leqslant \frac{a_{ij}}{p_j} \leqslant \frac{\beta}{p_i}$, and

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{ij}\lvert x_j\rvert^2}{p_j} \leqslant \frac{\beta}{p_i} \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \lvert x_j\rvert^2 = \frac{\beta}{p_i}\lVert x\rVert_{\ell^2}^2 < +\infty.$$

---

Alternatively, that follows from the computation coming after it. Note that all terms occurring in that line and the computation following it are nonnegative, so the computation makes sense and is valid whether

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} a_{ij} \frac{\lvert x_j\rvert^2}{p_j}\tag{1}$$

is finite or not. At the end, we reach a finite upper bound, so it follows that the series $(1)$ has a finite sum.

Comment: But the book defined Cauchy Schwarz inequality as the special case of Holder inequality for p=2. But to apply holders inequality for p=2 we need $l_2$ where the sums for each element of the form $\sum |x_i|^p$ are finite. Before knowing whether the sum is finite how can we use Cauchy Schwarz inequality then?

Comment: Hölder's inequality also holds when one - or both - of the sums/integrals is infinite. (Technically, we have a definition problem when one is $0$ and the other $\infty$, but the convention $0\cdot \infty = 0$ works in that case, as would $0\cdot \infty = \infty$.) If one factor is infinite, the inequality trivially holds (either because the left hand side is $0$, or because the right hand side is $\infty$).

Comment: @Jave I've added a different argument, maybe that looks more familiar.

Comment: Thank you so much ........